# Brownie project, failed to compile Solidity code: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I have a simple brownie project with a deploy.py and a solidity file. Both projects are fine. I get the same error, even though I delete the content in both files.

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

That's my Solidity-File:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Test {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    constructor() public {
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
        );

    function getCurrentPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I have a spelling mistake in my brownie-config.yaml file.
Instead of the / I need a =.

I had:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.0.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings: 
      - "@chainlink/smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.0.1"
```

It should be:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.0.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.0.1"
```